# VBA Object doesn't support property or method when filling webform

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, webforms

I'm trying to use the `Excel VBA` to fill a `web form` and then scrape some data.

I am stuck on how to put in the value that I want to search for.

In the source code, there is no id or name that I can use.

I tried with a class name but it is not working.

```
" Source code:

<input type="text" style="height: 28px; width: 170px; padding-left: 5px;" ng-model="model.FieldValue" placeholder="Enter a Value" ng-show="model.searchOptions.length &amp;&amp; model.searchOptions != 'SQE Quote Id'" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">


Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim html As HTMLDocument


    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "xxxx"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
'
    Set html = IE.Document
    IE.Document.getElementById("searchOptions").Click (2)
    IE.Document.getElementById("searchOptions").Value = "Access Qref"
    IE.Document.getelemenetbyclassname("ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched").Value = "00000"


'
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this an internal /private url?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put '.' between class names like below is working on my side.

```
 IE.Document.querySelector("input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched").Value = "00000"
```

Modified example:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim html As HTMLDocument


    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "D:\Backup20190913\tests\353.html"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

    Set html = IE.Document

    IE.Document.querySelector("input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched").Value = "00000"

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Ismail, can you please inform the status for this issue? If above answer solved the issue, then please try to accept the answer. If you found the solution by yourself then try to post your solution as an answer. If issue still persist then let us know about the current status for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The error is as it says. The method you are trying does not exist for that node. You are fine using a multi-valued class  (more than one class name for the element; denoted by several strings separated by spaces within the class attribute of the element) inside of the correct method `getElementsByClassName`, rather than `getelemenetbyclassname` then you need to index into the returned collection in order to exercise the `.click` method.

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")(0).Value = "00000" '0 for first node
```

However, as in other answer, if using `querySelector/querySelectorAll` to match by [css class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) then a multi-valued class must have the spaces between replaced with ".". Better still, try to select as few of those class names inside the multi-value as possible and the most selective which still match on the required node(s)

And please, I write this a lot on SO, use a proper page load wait:

```
While IE.busy Or IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```